# Manejando el valor de una variable entre varias funciones en proyecto de Kivy

Tags: python, funciones, variables, kivy

Sea el siguiente layout de mi app:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy buscando que cuando se pulse el botón "Pregunta acertada", la variable score = 10 y cuando se pulse el botón "Pregunta fallada", la variable score = -5
Para ambos casos, además el label morado muestra el valor de la variable score.
Actualmente tengo el siguiente error:

> *File "design.kv", line 54, in  on_release: root.showscore(score) NameError: name 'score' is not defined*

Más abajo doy una posible solución aunque no me funciona.

Mi código en python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext

    def goodanswer(self):
        score = 10
        return score 

    def badanswer(self):
        score = -5
        return score

    def showscore(self,score):
        self.ids['label3'].text = str(score)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```

Mi código en .kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    size: root.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 0

    #label1 muestra la pregunta
    Label:
        id: label1
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #label2 muestra la respuesta
    Label:
        id: label2
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        id: label3
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size


    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: root.goodanswer()
            on_release: root.score
            on_release: root.showscore(score)
        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release: root.badanswer()
            on_release: root.score
            on_release: root.showscore(score)
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "Mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showquestion()
```

Una opción que se me ocurre es la siguiente, usando la expresión `#:set name value` ver [doc.](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) :

```
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: 
                #:set score 10
            on_release: root.showscore(score)
        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release:
                #:set score -5
            on_release: root.showscore(score)
```

El problema es que parece que se hace de una forma global, prevaleciendo el último valor que se le ha dado, en este caso, -5. Quizás explore la vía de resolver este problema por el fichero .kv en vez de hacerlo por el .py, pero eso lo dejo para una pregunta posterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tal y como te dice el error la variable `score` nunca ha sido definida. Estas intentando cambiar el valor de una variable que no existe. Debes definirla, por ejemplo, como un atributo de instancia en el `__init__`. Dentro de los métodos `goodanswer`, `badanswer` y `showscore` debes hacer referencia a ella como un  atributo de clase, anteponiendo `self` al nombre. De igual forma en el .kv debes definir la clase a la que pertenece la variable, en este caso `root`.

Otra cosa importante es que no debes hacer esto:

```
on_release: root.goodanswer()
on_release: root.showscore(root.score)
```

Si haces esto te encontraras con respuestas inesperadas, de hecho si pulsas una vez el botón se ejecuta solo la primera línea, al segundo click lo hace la segunda, al tercero la primera de nuevo, etc. Para que en cada click ejecute más de una orden debes usar una sola linea:

```
on_release: root.goodanswer(), root.showscore(root.score)
```

El código quedaría así:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.score = 0

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext

    def goodanswer(self):
        self.score = 10

    def badanswer(self):
        self.score = -5

    def showscore(self,score):
        self.ids['label3'].text = str(self.score)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

**design.kv:**

```
<MyWidget>:
    size: root.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 0

    #label1 muestra la pregunta
    Label:
        id: label1
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #label2 muestra la respuesta
    Label:
        id: label2
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        id: label3
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size


    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: root.goodanswer(),root.showscore(root.score)

        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release: root.badanswer(), root.showscore(root.score)
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "Mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showquestion()
```

La forma simple de hacer esto es usar una `Property`, este tipo de variables permite la actualización automática de los valores en el Label:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    score = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

**design.kv:**

```
<MyWidget>:
    size: root.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 0

    #label1 muestra la pregunta
    Label:
        id: label1
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #label2 muestra la respuesta
    Label:
        id: label2
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        id: label3
        color: 1,0,1,1
        text: str(root.score)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size


    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: root.score += 10

        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release: root.score -= 5
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "Mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showquestion()
```

En este caso he modificado el comportamiento algo para mostrar otras capacidades. En este caso `score` vale 0 al iniciar. Cada vez que se pulsa <kbd>Respuesta Acertada</kbd> se suman 10 puntos y cada vez que se pulsa <kbd>Respuesta Fallada</kbd> se restan 5. Todo esto se hace desde el `kv`sin usar ningún método como haciamos antes pero observa que la variable `score` ha de ser declarada en el `main` tanto en este caso como en el anterior.

La gracia de la Property es que si modificamos su valor en cualquier momento automáticamente y desde cualquier lado se actualizan todos los widgets que usen ese valor, como es el caso de nuestro Label sin que tengamos que hacer nada más.

Creo que la mejor opción es la anterior pero se puede hacer de más formas, por ejemplo haciendo todo en el .kv, sin declarar siquiera la variable en el main.py:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design7.kv')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

**design.kv:**

```
<MyWidget>:
    score: 0
    size: root.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 0

    #label1 muestra la pregunta
    Label:
        id: label1
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #label2 muestra la respuesta
    Label:
        id: label2
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        id: label3
        color: 1,0,1,1
        text: str(root.score)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size


    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: root.score += 10

        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release: root.score -= 5
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "Mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showquestion()
```